# Angular JS $http request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to make a `$http` request with angular js to get a json object from google maps.

```
$http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + data[ 'street' ] + ',' + data[ 'city' ] + ',Deutschland' + '&sensor=true').success(function(mapData) {
                        angular.extend($scope, mapData);
    });
```

I read that I need to "inject" `$http` first, but I just cant get my head around how that works? I tried to do something like this:

```
angular.module('wmw', [])
.run(['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    function getTargetCords(data, $scope, $http) {
        var city = data[ 'city' ];
        return $http.get('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + data[ 'street' ] + ',' + data[ 'city' ] + ',Deutschland' + '&sensor=true').success(function(mapData) {
                    angular.extend($scope, mapData);
        });
    }
}]);
```

But in this case it is saying "getTargetCords is not defined" when I am trying to use it outside of this. I tried multiple different solutions and cant get my head around how to get this to work.

Edit: I think the reason why I need this function is maybe quite confusing, so here is my other code:

```
var onSuccess = function(position) {
    currentLat = position.coords.latitude ;
    currentLng = position.coords.longitude;
    var thecoords = [];
    $('#filter-list').empty();
    for(i = 0; i<locations.length;i++){
            thecoords = getTargetCords(locations[i]);
            var distance = calculateDistance(currentLat, currentLng, thecoords[0], thecoords[1]);
            addItemToList(locations[i], distance);
    }   
};

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
function onError(error) {
    alert('Aktueller Standort konnte nicht berechnet werden');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
```

We have different locations and I need the distance for each location.

Please note: as I didn't quite finish the angular part, the "thecoords[0]", "thecoods[1]" are obviously wrong values right now

Comment: How are you trying to use the function outside?

Comment: Something like "var data = getTargetCords(locations[i], $scope, $http)"

Comment: You mean, outside the angular app ?

Comment: On the risk that I'm embarrassing myself now... Yeah, outside of it. Isn't that possible?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but you should not do it.

Comment: I don't see any reason you would do that.

Comment: Awesome, glad is working. gl :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE 2**

http://pastebin.com/WUuYFAnX

When we wish to call `AngularJS` code from within a legacy app, think of the AngularJS code as being a small application existing within a protected container in your legacy application; You cannot make calls to it directly, but you can make remote calls.

You can use the Id of the HTML element where the Controller resides. (Not recommended) but you can do the following:

**HTML Changes, We need `ng-controller` and `ng-app`**

```
<html ng-app="wmw">
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl" id="MainCtrlId">
   ...
</body>
</html>
```

**Angular Code & Native JS**

```
var app = angular.module('wmw', []);

    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

               $scope.getTargetCords = function (data) {

               $http.get(data).success(function (response) {
                    var responseData = JSON.parse(response);
                    console.log(responseData);
               });
            };
    });



function getCords() {
    var city = activeDest['city'];
    var destUrl = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=' + activeDest['street'] + ',' + activeDest['city'] + ',Deutschland' + '&sensor=true';

    var MyAngularScope = angular.element($("#MainCtrlId")).scope();
    //Now call your angular method.
    MyAngularScope.getTargetCords(destUrl);
}
```

For more details on this technique look at this [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/peterdrinnan/2nPnB/16/).

It is strongly recommended that you redo the application to work within the Angular Ecosystem instead of doing the above.

Here is a simple angular setup, separate Angular `Controllers` into their on `JS`files and Import them in your `HTML` like you would with any other `JS` file.

```
var app = angular.module('wmw', []);
app.controller('YourCtrlName', function ($scope, $http) {

    //Inside your controller you can define your "scope functions".
    $scope.getTargetCords= function(){

          $http.get('urlToGet').success(function(response) {
               var responseData = JSON.parse(response);
               console.log(responseData); 
          });

    };
});
```

Now in your HTML You can have something like this:

```
<div ng-app="wmw">
  <div ng-controller="YourCtrlName">
      <button ng-click="getTargetCords()">GET DATA</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

You were receiving:

> getTargetCords is not defined

Because you were attempting to access an Angular controller method from outside the Angular Application.

Comment: Can I somehow call this function from my javascript, not from html? I am getting the error "getDataFromGoogle is not defined" :/

Comment: Yeah you def can! Just make sure your call is happening after you define the function and not before. In your question i don't really see where you are calling the function. Try to structure your Angular App differently. Look at my example.

Comment: I know this is maybe a bit too much to ask for, but would you look into my file to see if I am missing something out?

Comment: Yeah no problem. Use pastebin or some other service to paste the code then include a link in your question.

Comment: It's a little messy in there, as someone else worked on this previously and I am just changing stuff, I suggest you just strg+f and search for " 'wmw' ", http://pastebin.com/q3Hp8Def

Comment: Now that i see the code, why are you using angular for just one call? I see what you are attempting to do here. Basically you want to have angular `$http.get()`  but call this from outside the Angular ecosystem.... Why not just move everything in that *Disaster of an app* no offense :P, into Angular Ecosystem and make it all work nice together. Everything in the app is using global functions anyways, no structure at all. You can get all this and separate it into controller and services as needed. It will be 1000% cleaner.

Comment: The only problem with that would be, that I have never worked with angular before. I don't even know what a "service" is. And I have to finish this project to monday. Is there no other way to use the $http.get? I cant use ajax because of the asyncronous call, so I don't know what else than angular I could use.. Thank you really much for the information! If there is no other way, I will have to learn about angular in 2 days.

Comment: I made changes to the code you voided via pastebin, hopefully this helps you! Also, look at my updated answer which explains how to talk to angular from outside your raw app. http://pastebin.com/WUuYFAnX

Comment: Now I am getting "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$injector/modulerr?p0=wmw&p1=Error%3A%20…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.3.14%2Fangular.min.js%3A17%3A381)" :( I "installed" angular-route.js but still getting it

Comment: Got it to work! I needed to define the module outside of the doc.ready of jquery.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you got it running, GL :)